# EURT Tempo now completely useless?

Tags: token

Is Tempo Crypto now completely dead? Exit scam?

Tempo does not mention EURT anywhere any more on their website, exchange rate on StellarX is really poor and the spread is almost 50%. Contacted support via form and they asked  me for my Stellar address and then "put me on hold" for more than a month now. Asked again but will have to wait after the weekend if I get any better answer now.

I still hold some "small" (in comparison) amounts of EURT, hoping that they will recover...